# Adding Gestures From Storyboard To Cells

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I have initialized a longPressGesture in storyboard and I want to add it to cells in the `collectionView`.

**The problem is**: the gesture only works on the last added cell in the `collectionView`

this is my code:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     MyCollectionCell *cell = (MyCollectionCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell addGestureRecognizer:longPressGesture];
    return cell;
}
```

.h file:

```
IBOutlet UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressGesture;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your gesture target method do same operation for all cell, then Create New `UILongPressGesture` every time and assign it to cell for `UICollectionView` like

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     MyCollectionCell *cell = (MyCollectionCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

     UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                                          initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture:)];
     longPressGesture.minimumPressDuration = 1.5; 

    [showUserMap addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];

    [cell addGestureRecognizer:longPressGesture];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I know this works, but I want to add different gestures to each cell, and it will be easier, and less code, when I do it in storyboard. Do you know a way to let that work ?